# Data da última publicação

Tags: c#, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2010

Estamos tendo problemas com publicação. Usamos TFS para versionar a aplicação. Porem há duas pessoas fazendo a publicação final(não aceito isso). Há como eu ir no Visual Studio e ver a data da minha última publicação em minha máquina?

Comment: Botão lado direito na solução -> Source Control -> View History ??

Comment: @CesarMiguel, Mas o History não mostra a data do último Publish. Mostra o histórico do TFS, mas o publish ele não mostra.

Comment: e se fores mesmo à página web do TFS?

Comment: Se as publicações são feitas apenas a partir de um publish no visual studio, acredito que não há maneira de saber. Se for o caso, eu sugiro remover a permissão de escrita do(s) respectivo(s) recurso(s) que esteja(m) efetuando publicações indevidas no(s) respectivo(s) servidor(es). Agora caso você esteja usando o Team Build para efetuar as publicações, é possível ver pelo histórico de builds no TFS.

Comment: @ConradClark, não eu publico diretamente em uma pasta e depois subo para os devidos ambientes. Não uso o team build.

Comment: É possível retirar a permissão destas pessoas para esta `pasta`? Se você realmente precisa saber quando foi a última vez que você publicou da sua máquina, acho que você pode incluir um passo a mais após o publish para gravar a data atual em um arquivo ou alguma espécie de log. Se quiser detalhes de como fazer isso, posso responder a pergunta.

Comment: @ConradClark, pode sim responder a pergunta. Preciso fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Ok, um jeito simples de criar um log para gravar a data toda vez que um `Publish` for executado é alterando o processo de build para gerar um arquivo de log após o publish. Tenha nota de que este arquivo está sendo gerado da sua máquina, portanto vale apenas para os publishes que **você** realizar.

Primeiro de tudo, crie um arquivo .targets na solução, no projeto, onde vc preferir e com o nome que você preferir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo deve conter o código a seguir ou similar:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="CustomPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <LogFile Include="$(SolutionDir)log.txt"/>
        <DateTimeNow Include="data1">
            <Text>
                $([System.DateTime]::Now)
            </Text>
        </DateTimeNow>
    </ItemGroup>

    <WriteLinesToFile
        File="@(LogFile)"
        Lines="@(DateTimeNow->'%(Text)')"
        Overwrite="true"
        Encoding="Unicode"/>
</Target>
```

Acho que lendo dá pra entender o que ele faz, é um `Target` que executa sempre após o `AfterPublish`, executando o código especificado. Estou setando a hora/data atual (que sera a hora/data da publicação) para uma variavel e escrevendo em um arquivo chamado log.txt, que vai ficar na pasta raiz da solução.

Depois de salvar este arquivo, clique em "Unload Project" no seu projeto, edite o arquivo (Comando edit xxx.csproj), e acrescente a seguinte linha no final, ainda dentro da tag `Project`:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)postPublish.targets" />
```

Este caminho vai mudar dependendo de onde você colocar o arquivo targets que você criou. Após efetuar um `Publish`, o comando será executado e vai gerar um arquivo de log com a data.

Um detalhe importante: Se não for um console/windows app/ coisa do genero, talvez o nome no `AfterTargets` mude. Procurando na internet ou até vasculhando nos logs do msbuild vc consegue saber fácil o nome que vai precisar usar.